# Поясните смысл предложения (для краткости Веллер перефразирован)

Tags: значение-слов

Карл Маркс был **иждивенцем эксплуататорских талантов** фабриканта Энгельса (как можно быть иждивенцем **чего либо**, тем более не материального).

Comment: Метафора..

Comment: > Юрий Герман. Дорогой мой человек (1961) ― Там я хоть в самой малой, капельной мере, но способствую делу освобождения, прости за высокий стиль, а здесь **я иждивенец войны**…

Answer (score 1):

На мой вкус такое употребление не совсем соответствует нормам, но а принципе вполне понятно и достаточно выразительно выразительно. Своего рода окказионализм. 
Иждивенец обычно "чей", а не "кого", поэтому и возникает некоторое недоумение, вполне, впрочем в духе приемов данного автора.
А замена одушевленного объекта на неодушевленный, даже не предметный, отвлеченный сама по себе не может рассматриваться как недопустимый эрратив.